# Unable to access property in ember.js view

Tags: google-maps, ember.js

I have a view of a Google map and I want it to expose the map so I can bind to it from another object. The problem is that since I can only instantiate the map on `didInsertElement` (instantiating it directly won't work since the div hasn't been rendered yet) I'm unable to access the true value of the map (it always returns null).

Here's my code:

```
Places = Ember.Application.create();
Places.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName : 'div',    
    map : null,               
    didInsertElement : function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('map', new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316),
        zoom: 15
        }));
        this.get('map'); // Returns the value of the map OK
    }
});

Places.searchController = Ember.Object.create({
    mapBinding: 'Places.MapView.map' // Doesn't work
}
```

Here's the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#view Places.MapView id="map"}}{{/view}}          
</script>
```

If I set any other property within `MapView` directly I have no problem binding to it. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my controllers, I usually bind to a "model" object and not a view object.

Maybe try setting the map to a different object.

```
Places = Ember.Application.create();

Places.MapData = Ember.Object.create({
    map: null
});

Places.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName : 'div',    
    map : null,               
    didInsertElement : function() {
        this._super();
        Places.MapData.set('map', new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316),
        zoom: 15
        }));
    }
});

Places.searchController = Ember.Object.create({
    mapBinding: 'Places.MapData.map'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `searchController` you are binding to the map property of the `MapView` ***class***.  The class does not have a map property.  When the class is instantiated and `didInsertElement` runs, the map property is added to a `MapView` ***instance***.  To make your binding work you'll need to bind to the map property of the instantiated view, not the class.

Comment: I tried `Places.mapView = Places.MapView.create({})` and `{{#view Places.mapView id="map"}}{{/view}}` but then the map doesn't appear on the screen.